# AngularJS pop-up chatbox

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angularjs, angular-bootstrap

I've been writing the back-end of a web-application using angularJS. The application should allow a user to contact another user via a pop-up chat box (the type in gmail/fbook). I've been trying to skip using jquery and write this component in angularJS using angular-bootstrap modals, but the user also needs to be able to navigate around the page while the chatbox is open.

I know StackOverflow prefers more direct answerable questions but I haven't found much around the web about writing this in angularJS and I was wondering whether anyone knew how to write a pop-up chatbox using angularJS, HTML, and CSS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one of the AngularJS's weaknesses. There are different ways of doing it but nothing that is the "standard" way. You have to basically code it from scratch.

People have implemented different approaches. Here are a few

http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngDialog

http://fundoo-solutions.github.io/angularjs-modal-service/

http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/building-an-angularjs-modal-service

For my own projects I ended up doing something myself. If none of these do the trick, then you might have to as well.

Comment: You are right, seems to me angular author didn't have this kind of usage in their mind when they write angular. Can you give more hints or more details on your approach with your real projects on this matter?

Comment: @PhamHuyAnh sure, take a look at the source code for my UI library. http://github.com/thinkingmedia/thinkingmedia-ui specifically this file https://github.com/thinkingmedia/thinkingmedia-ui/blob/master/src/UI/Services/Modal/Modal.js